# Generate PL/SQL from UML

Tags: oracle, uml

Are there any tool (open source or freeware) to generate the PL/SQL code (with objects) from a UML Diagram?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may try to write your own transformation through the Eclipse Modeling Tool Project. You need Papyrus, as UML graphical editor, to create UML models conform to the Eclipse's ECORE (which is the Eclipse implementation of the MOF meta-meta-model). Then you can write Acceleo scripts describing how to turn UML elements (i.e. classes, stereotypes, properties, operations, etc.) into the code you need (i.e. PL/SQL). Acceleo is the Eclipse implementation of the MOFM2T language which is the OMG standard for model to text transformations (http://www.omg.org/spec/MOFM2T).

Comment: It sounds harsh, but if you don't know which code to write you should not generate it, imo.

Comment: yes in order to define a model to text transformation you may need to know the source meta-model and the target meta-model. You thus should know what kind of model you need to generate, code included.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to generate java code from an UML diagram then to add ORM annotations in your java code and then use the dali Eclipse project to generate your SQL code.